# Show that $\ker W$ is $A$-invariant?

Tags: linear-algebra, dynamical-systems

Consider the system.:

$$\dot x = Ax$$
$$y= Cx $$

The observability matrix then will be 
$$ W= \left(\begin{matrix}
        C \\
        CA \\
        CA^2\\
        \vdots \\ 
        CA^{n-1}
        \end{matrix} \right)$$

1.) How can I show that $\ker{W}$ is $A$-invariant?

I know that $\ker W =$ {$x ; Wx=0$}
I know that for a linear subspace $V$ to be $A$-invariant means $AV \subset V$

2.) Suppose $V$ is a $A$ invariant subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $V \subset \ker C$, how can I show that $V \subset \ker W$?

Try:

1.) I have to show that $A \ker W \subset \ker W$. How can I express $A\ker W$ ?

2.) $AV\subset V \subset \ker C \implies V \subset \ker W$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to show that $x\in\ker W\Rightarrow Ax\in W$. In other words, you need to show that
$$
\begin{cases}
Cx = 0,\\
CAx = 0,\\
\vdots\\
CA^{n-1}x = 0,
\end{cases}
\Rightarrow
\begin{cases}
CAx = 0,\\
CA^2x = 0,\\
\vdots\\
CA^nx = 0.
\end{cases}
$$
The first $n-1$ equalities on the RHS follow immediately from the last $n-1$ equalities on the LHS. To show $CA^nx=0$, apply [Cayley-Hamilton theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%E2%80%93Hamilton_theorem), which guarantees that $A^n$ as a linear combination of $I,A,A^2,\ldots,A^{n-1}$.

As to the second question, if $x\in V$, then by $A$-invariance of $V$, we have $A^kx\in V$ for all $k=0,1,2,\ldots$. However, as $V\subset\ker C$, it follows that $CA^kx=0$ for every $k\ge0$. Hence the result follows.

Comment: Ah thanks. That makes sense. But maybe you can tell something about the second question ? :)

Comment: Why do we multiply on the right side? Why $CAx, CA^2x$ etc and not $ACx, ACAx...$ ?

Comment: You want to show that $V\subset W$. That means for any $x\in V$, you need to show that $Wx=0$. But $Wx=0$ is equivalent to $Cx=CAx=\ldots=CA^{n-1}x=0$, so of course we want to consider $Cx,CAx,CA^2x$ etc. rather than $ACx,ACAx,\ldots$.

Comment: Nice. This was not too difficult :)